# Javascript MenuBar with TickMarks beside Menu Items

Tags: javascript

I have a MenuBar as shown with values One , Two and Three currently .Onclick of that Menu Item (For Example One) i am showing a Label One

How can i have  a TickMark beside the Menu Item when it is selected and remove the TickMark when it is deselected .

This is my Menu Bar Code

```
<ul id="sddm" style="width:420px;margin:0 auto">
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m1')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Test</a>
        <div id="m1" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#" OnClick="MyFunction();">One</a>
        <a href="#">Two</a>
        <a href="#">Three</a>
        </div>
    </li>
```

This is the style sheet i am using currently

```
#sddm
{   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 30}

#sddm li
{   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    font: bold 11px arial}

#sddm li a
{   display: block;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #5970B2;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none}

#sddm li a:hover
{   background: #49A3FF}

#sddm div
{   position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #EAEBD8;
    border: 1px solid #5970B2}

    #sddm div a
    {   position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        width: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #EAEBD8;
        color: #2875DE;
        font: 11px arial}

    #sddm div a:hover
    {   background: #49A3FF;
        color: #FFF}
```

Please help

Comment: Mind if i present you jquery solution???

Comment: No issues , atleast something should work .

Comment: looks like your have badly messed up menu (html), just check updates, and modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The similar working code

```
<style>
#sddm li.ch{
        background: url('remove.png') no-repeat;
}
</style>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function (){
            $('#sddm li').click(function (){
                if($(this).hasClass('ch')){
                        $(this).removeClass('ch');
                }
                else{
                        $(this).addClass('ch');
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
<ul id="sddm" style="width:420px;margin:0 auto">
    <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And your image
[image: remove.png]

Comment: Thank you very much , here the alert is getting called on click of Menu Item , but the code isn't working (I mean adding of Tick Mark Images on to Menu Item )  This is my code :        $(function (){
  
  
            $('#sddm li').click(function (){
   
   alert('ddd');
                if($(this).hasClass('ch')){
                        $(this).removeClass('ch');
                }
                else{
                        $(this).addClass('ch');
                }
            })
        })

  #li{
background: url('http://www.incorporate.net.au/incprod/images/tick_icon.gif') no-repeat;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
You have forcefully made the code accepted :) , Any help why this not displaying an Image beside the Menu Item 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function (){


            $('#sddm li').click(function (){




                if($(this).hasClass('ch')){
                        $(this).removeClass('ch');
                }
                else{
                        $(this).addClass('ch');
                }
            })
        })



    </script>

</head>
<body>





    <!-- body -->
    <div id="center">



<!-- dd menu -->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var timeout         = 500;
var closetimer      = 0;
var ddmenuitem      = 0;

// open hidden layer
function mopen(id)
{   
    // cancel close timer
    mcancelclosetime();

    // close old layer
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    // get new layer and show it
    ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
    ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';

}
// close showed layer
function mclose()
{
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

// go close timer
function mclosetime()
{
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, timeout);
}

// cancel close timer
function mcancelclosetime()
{
    if(closetimer)
    {
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;
    }
}


</script>
<style>
#sddm
{   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 30}

#sddm li
{   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    font: bold 11px arial}

#sddm li a
{   display: block;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #5970B2;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none}

#sddm li a:hover
{   background: #49A3FF}

#sddm div
{   position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #EAEBD8;
    border: 1px solid #5970B2}

    #sddm div a
    {   position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        width: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #EAEBD8;
        color: #2875DE;
        font: 11px arial}

    #sddm div a:hover
    {   background: #49A3FF;
        color: #FFF}



        #ch{
background: url('http://www.incorporate.net.au/incprod/images/tick_icon.gif') no-repeat;
}




</style>


<!-- div class="sample" style="margin-bottom: 15px;height:42px;"><span -->
<ul id="sddm" style="width:420px;margin:0 auto">
    <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m1')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Test</a>
        <div id="m1" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#" id="kii" >Hide All</a>
        <a href="#" OnClick="MyFunction();" >Show All</a>
        <a href="#" id="Oner" OnClick="MyFunction();" >One</a>
        <a href="#" OnClick="MyFunction();" >Two</a>
        </div>
    </li>


</ul>



<div id="one" style="visibility:hidden" >

      <LABEL FOR=user style="width:420px;margin:0 auto" ACCESSKEY=U>Google Search Bar :</LABEL>

<div>  


<div id="two" style="visibility:hidden" >

      <LABEL FOR=user style="width:420px;margin:0 auto" ACCESSKEY=U>Map Type control:</LABEL>

<div>

<div id="three" style="visibility:hidden" >

      <LABEL FOR=user style="width:420px;margin:0 auto" ACCESSKEY=U>Zoom Control :</LABEL>

<div>


<div id="four" style="visibility:hidden" >

      <LABEL FOR=user style="width:420px;margin:0 auto" ACCESSKEY=U>Latitude/Longitude Display:</LABEL>

<div>




</body>
</html>
```